# How to do port forward on a VPS?

Tags: networking

I have a VPS on Ubuntu 13.10 x86_64   it has an:
public IP: say 1.1.1.1
private IP: 198.168.1.33

and I want to redirect all my incoming traffic to port 443 to my private IP 198.168.1.33

I have only SSH access to the server, can anyone tell me the command to do it? Thx.

Comment: This question would be better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) as it doesn't directly relate to programming, but if your VPS has a public IP and a private one on the same interface, why not just have your applications listen on the right address?  They'll be Internet-accessible without any port forwarding.  Port forwarding is for internal networks when you have a gateway intercepting all traffic on a single IP to multiple private IPs.

Comment: I have a public IP and a private IP on diff. interfaces, first on eth0 & 2nd on eth1. and I want to forward incoming traffic to port 443 to my private IP (198.168.x.x) that is on eth1.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use Apache and either

- Setup a virtual host - see [Examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/vhosts/examples.html)

OR

- Use [Apache Proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am not configuring a web server.  There's another reason for port forwards